# Visualize ..count.. in a line graph with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame with tweets (containing a timecode, tweet-id, text, etc.) and want to visualise the amount of tweets per hour. It works fine with a bar graph:

[image: Bar graph of tweets per hour]

I use the following code to produce the bar graph (`created` stores the timecode of a tweet in POSIX format):

```
  ggplot(data=tweets_frame, aes(x=created)) + 
     geom_bar(aes(fill=..count..), binwidth=3600) + 
     scale_x_datetime("Time") + 
     scale_y_continuous("Tweets")
```

I want to produce the same graph, but as line graph instead of as bar graph.

I tried to just replace `geom_bar` with `geom_line`:

```
  ggplot(data=tweets_frame, aes(x=created)) + 
     geom_line(aes(fill=..count..), binwidth=3600) + 
     scale_x_datetime("Time") + 
     scale_y_continuous("Tweets")
```

Which resulted in this error message:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'count' not found

I cannot figure out how to specify the `..count..` in a line graph.

Comment: we cld rly use a  `dput(tweets_frame)` (or part of it) in the example

Comment: The data frame has a `created` column, that contains a posix timestamp, and then columns for the text of the tweet, tweet-id, screenname of author, etc... I can upload a sample later, but the question is general and not specific to the data.

Comment: I agree with hrbrmstr.  It'd be a lot better if you provided sample data and showed what you have tried.  Are you looking for something like this:  `ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=hp)) + geom_line(aes(fill=..count..), stat="bin", binwidth=10)`?

Comment: @Jota ok, the missing part in my solution was `stat="bin" `, and I also found that _By default, `geom_bar` uses `stat="bin"`_ and `geom_line` does not. That's why I did not think about it. Do you want to add your comment as an answer, @Jota.

Comment: I updated the question to give more detailed information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can switch from `stat="identity"`, the default setting with `geom_line`,  to `stat="bin"`, which allows the use of `..count..`.  I used the `mtcars` data for this example, and I arbitrarily set `binwidth` to 10.

```
ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=hp)) + geom_line(aes(fill=..count..), stat="bin", binwidth=10).
```